# When do you release a static Context

Tags: android

Everyone will tell you that keep a static `Context` keeps it from being GC'ed and that's bad. But if you need some static resources which depend on your `Context`, you need that static field. So when do you release it? I've looked at the Facebook SDK source and they keep a reference. Is there a way to hook up to the application lifecycle to release the reference, or is a static application context acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

An *application* context is ok as it will never be garbage collected while your application is running any way. What you don't want to do is hold an activity context as it contains all sorts of other, non-context related references.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but here is an example of a class which stores the application context.

```
class myClass {
    private final Context mContext;

    public myClass(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public String getSomeString() {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.name);
    }
}
```